# Como hacer que mi funcion solo afecte al elemento que se le esta dando el click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, es6

tengo esta funcion, pero cuando se ejecuta se aplica sobre todos los elementos y ya que estoy usando de referencia su estilo css para agarrar los elementos, todos se pintan y no unicamente el que se le da click

```
 $('.vermas').click(function(){

    $('.elemento-preguntas').addClass( "elemento-activado" );
    $('.respuesta-icon').text( "!" );
    $('.respuesta').css( 'display','block');
    $('.vermas').css( 'display','none');

  })
```

Comment: Estás accediendo a las clases, es obvio que aplicará a todos los elementos con la misma clase

Answer (score 2):

Se aplica a todos por que estas accediendo directamente a su class la cual es genérica supongo ya que no se ve todo tu código; si quieres que solo se aplique a un elemento en específico usa el id que tiene asignado

```
$('#id_unico').click(function(){
//aquí debería ir el código que quieres afectar de los demás elementos pero todos por medio de su id que ayudan a identificar un elemento de manera única
})
```

Recuerda que para acceder a una class es **.class** y para acceder por medio de su id es **#id**

//ACTUALIZACIÓN

```
 $('#boton_id').click(function(){

    $('#id_uno').addClass( "elemento-activado" );
    $('#id_dos').text( "!" );
    $('#id_tres').css( 'display','block');
    $('#boton_id').css( 'display','none');

  })
```

Comment: lo que sucede es que quiero que este evento se replique en varios botones y evitar crear un evento por cada botón por eso no uso el id, ya que son varios botones que haran lo mismo pero solo cuando se presione.

Comment: pues una vez que le das click al botón principal accediendolo por medio de su id como en el ejemplo dentro accede a cada uno de ellos pero también por su id no por su class y aplicale los cambios sería la forma en que yo lo haria

Answer (score 2):

Haciendolo asi me funciono

```
$('.elemento-preguntas').click(function(){

    $(this).addClass('elemento-activado')
    $(this).find('span').text( "!" );
    $(this).find('button').css( 'display','none');
    $(this).find('p').css( 'display','block');


  })
```

Answer (score 0):

[Usa la propiedad this como selector de jQuery del elemento](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-this-selectores-jquery-5311/)

```
 $('.vermas').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass( "elemento-activado" );
    })
```